# Cleaner alternative for "sucks".

Tags: offensive-language, synonyms, euphemisms, minced-oaths

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formal alternative for “suck”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74576/formal-alternative-for-suck)

Since the word "sucks" does not have an [origin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22786/what-is-the-origin-of-the-words-sucker-and-it-sucks) that would make it a good word to use in many contexts, I want to know whether there is a cleaner alternative. I tried searching the thesaurus, but couldn't find any. Is there a cleaner alternative that can be used in all the contexts that "sucks" is used?

Comment: It depends. Can you give example context and sentences in which you'd want 'sucks' replaced? Are you  wondering about 'Your dog died? That sucks' or 'That guy sucks at math.' or 'Go suck an egg' or 'Suck on it, dipwad!' or 'Where the bee sucks, there suck I" or etc, etc, etc. All these contexts are different.

Comment: Why look for an alternative for *all contexts*? A one-size-fits-all word makes one's message almost meaningless. English has such a rich lexicon, why not find a specific word to express exactly what you mean? :)

Comment: Not a good word, eh? Related: ["Speaking in my official capacity as a Pulitzer Prize winner, Mr. Schneider, your movie sucks."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4223/why-do-you-suck-at-xyz)

Comment: Downvoters stink I guess.

Comment: -1 Please show the result of your research.

Comment: "That's no good" @CodeBlue

Comment: despite the title, the supposed duplicate question deals with the phrase "suck at", not "sucks" in general.

Answer (score 6):

There is [*stinks*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stink#Verb):

> v. (intransitive, informal) To be greatly **inferior**; to perform badly.

This is comparable to the definition of [*sucks*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suck#Verb):

> v. (intransitive, slang) To be **inferior** or objectionable: a general term of disparagement, sometimes used with at to indicate a particular area of deficiency.

Also, [*blows*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blow#Verb):

> v. (intransitive, slang) To be very undesirable (see also **suck**).

Instead of saying "this sucks", one could say "[*shucks*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shucks)!" or "[*nuts*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nuts#Interjection)!" This would depend on how much something "sucks", of course.

> **shucks**: Interjection
> (colloquial) Exclamatory response to a minor disappointment.
>
> **nuts**: Interjection
>  Indicates annoyance, anger, or disappointment.

To describe the sex act, you could say [*fellatio*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fellatio).

Finally, you can opt for sarcasm: "that's *interesting*" instead of "that sucks". This relies [on delivery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasm#Vocal_indication) and how well your audience knows you, otherwise your words may be taken at face value.

Comment: Agh, two downvotes. What am I doing wrong? Soliciting critiques, else I can delete.

Comment: "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise". Generally speaking, well reasoned answers which provide reliable citations to back up their claims are well received.

Comment: @ΜετάEd Point taken. :)

Comment: I think the OP wanted cleaner (and possibly more formal?) alternatives to this word, devoid of any of the sexual flavor of the word "sucks". And so, suggesting "blows" and "fellatio" makes it appear as though you misinterpreted the question by mistake or, worse, on purpose.

Answer (score 6):

While *sucks* is a verb form, most of the terms that convey similar meaing are adjectives. The primary connotation of *sucks* is that the referent, whether a person, object, action or state of being, is *very bad* or *awful* (as in *That sucks*).

There are numerous [synomyms](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/awful) for *awful*, such as

> abominable
>
> atrocious
>
> dreadful
>
> terrible
>
> unspeakable
>
> painful
>
> nasty
>
> unpleasant

[and](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=awful)

> lousy
>
> pathetic
>
> poor
>
> wretched
>
> abysmal
>
> dismal
>
> ghastly
>
> mean
>
> miserable
>
> worthless

While each of these might not be an ideal choice *in all the contexts* as the OP requests, many of them might suit in the particular context he or she is actually using.