# Is f**kstick really an abusive word?

Tags: meaning, pejorative-language, offensive-language

I have heard the word *fuckstick* in a lot of Hollywood movies, most notably in 'The Shawshank Redemption'.

What is this word even meant to convey? An insult? Is it even abusive? Or is just a combination of two random words?

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/406/how-bad-is-the-f-word-really).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder if the *stick* part could have been chosen by analogy with *dipstick*, which was used as a mild insult starting in the 1920s. (Of course, "Shawshank Redemption" isn't *really* from that time period, but was written recently by Stephen King, so even if someone from the 1920s wouldn't really have said that, it wouldn't invalidate the theory.) There is no way to really know for sure, unless we ask King himself; and even he might not consciously know why he chose that.

*Dipstick* can still be used today, but remains very mild as far as insults go.  Changing *dip* to *fuck* would take that mild insult and make it into something much more offensive. I have certainly heard *fuckstick* before, but it isn't particularly common compared to other similar insults.

I have to say, as an English speaker, I find it to be one of the more amusing insult constructions involving the word *fuck* (because it is almost silly), but if said in the right manner by someone in the right situation, could still make the name-receiver quite quite angry and insulted.

---

As mentioned by Martha, a *fuckstick* could also be interpreted as a dildo, or something with this sort of sexual connotation.

Comment: Interpreted literally, a *fuckstick* is a dildo. For whatever that's worth.

Comment: @Martha - or any stick like object used for fucking.

Comment: It's also possible that "f**kstick" could be a contraction of "f**cking dispstick", similar to "f**ktard" being a contraction of "f**king retard".  Sadly, the "F-Bomb" is surprisingly versatile in its daily usage.

Comment: Amusing..? Hilarious! I have to remember that one.. ;)

Comment: @Martha: people never call dildos *fucksticks* though (or do they?  I might not be the person to ask).  Still I added your mention because certainly there can be a sexually vulgar connotation.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: for some reason, I've never had occasion to refer to a dildo in conversation, period. So I wouldn't know. I'm just saying that literally, fuck + stick = stick you fuck with = dildo.

Comment: @Martha: Well, neither you nor I can make that claim again after today :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: yeah, where's the brain soap when you need it...

Comment: It is also possible that fuck*stick* is a phonetic variation of fuck*wad*, which is a fairly common insult.

Comment: @oosterwal: Probably all of these are correct, depending on the person.